# Propagation of multiple photons in a waveguide lattice

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, waveguide

Hamiltonian describing photonic lattice made of N elements can be written as:

$$H = \hbar\sum_{i=1}^{N} (\beta_{i} \hat{a}_{i}^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{N}\kappa _{ij} \hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{i})$$

Propagation dynamics of a single photon is governed by the Heisenberg equations of motion:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \hat{a}_{q}^{\dagger}}{\mathrm{d} z} = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[\hat{a}_{q}^{\dagger},\hat{H}]
$$

Solution of these equations is:

$$
\hat{a}_{q}^{\dagger}(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{N}U_{q,j}(z)\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger}(0)
$$

Then probability of finding photon in waveguide *q* if it was coupled in waveguide *m* is:

$$
\left \langle \psi (0) \left | \hat{a}_{q}^{\dagger}(z)\hat{a}_{q}(z)\right | \psi (0)\right \rangle = \left | U_{q,m}(z) \right |^{2}
$$
Where $$ \psi (0)=\hat{a}_{m}^{\dagger}(0)\left| 0\right\rangle $$
And $$U = exp(i\hat{H}z/\hbar)$$

I want to derive propagation dynamics of multiple photons coupled in such system.

**So my question is:** How these equations will change in case of multiple photons? Obviously, initial state will consist of multiple mode operators, but how Heisnberg equation of motion would change and solution respective to it?

Comment: http://science.sciencemag.org/content/329/5998/1500 or there is probably an arxiv version if you dont have access

Comment: Thank you, I think now I have general perspective on how to derive equations for arbitrary multi-photon case.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help. Large photonic networks are pretty fashionable at the moment so there is a lot of literature

Comment: I'm still having trouble with physical understanding though. I see now that I can use Heisengerg equation of motion  for operator A, where A(0)|0> would represent arbitrary initial state, but suppose I found solution - A(z), what would it physically mean?

Comment: Suppose you have something more clear such as $a^{\dagger}\left(z\right)a\left(z\right)$, do you have any intuition for what this might mean?

Comment: Is it a photon number operator at point z? I struggle with understanding of $$\left \langle\psi (0) \left |\hat{A}\hat{A}^{*} \right | \psi (0)\right \rangle $$ , where $$\hat{A}\left | 0 \right \rangle=\frac{\hat{a}^{\dagger n}}{\sqrt{n!}}  \left | 0 \right \rangle$$

Comment: can you see that that, according to the way you have defined your operators $A\lvert 0 \rangle=\lvert n \rangle$?

Comment: yes, i can see that, it is by the definition of the Fock states

Comment: I am not sure what your question is then really can you try and be more concrete and ask a specific question?

Comment: I want to understand physical meaning of  $$\left \langle\psi (0) \left |\hat{A}(z)\hat{A}^{*} (z)\right | \psi (0)\right \rangle$$ , where $$ \hat{A}(0)\left | 0 \right \rangle=\frac{\hat{a}^{\dagger n}(0)}{\sqrt{n!}}  \left | 0 \right \rangle $$ and A(z) is a solution of Heisenberg equation of motion. More specific: is it mean number of photons at point z or is it probability of finding exactly n photons in a waveguide?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62848/discussion-between-chris2807-and-fedor-kiselev).